# Android Form Scrolling with Translucent Status Bar

Tags: android, statusbar

I am targeting SDK 21,  Min SDK 15, Testing on API 19 device (Android 4.4.4)

I have this code in my Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

    setTranslucentStatus();

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void setTranslucentStatus() {
    getWindow()
            .addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
}
```

It works, with one problem.  In the layout I have a ScrollView.  The ScrollView is not scrolling.   However, if I comment out the call to setTranslucentStatus() scrolling works just fine.

By the way, the theme is NoActionBar

Any clue as to why the ScrollView would refuse to scroll when the status bar is translucent?

Comment: Same annoying problem here, In Lollipop I can't get the ScrollView to work while setting Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor in my v21/styles.xml. Tried to set the filViewPort, and the AdjustResize parameters, none of them would do.

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Also have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already found a solution for that, but if you use ConstraintLayout should solve this annoying bug.

A sample layout would look like this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the attribute of scroll view 
--  scrollbars: none in scroll view it makes the scroll view to scroll with out scrollbars
 No need of translucent flag just remove it